# What widget kit / framework is Woopra using?

Tags: gwt, widget, look-and-feel

If you use Woopra, you probably know that several months ago they released a web based analysis tool. I was surprised by how smooth and well designed it was. Taking a look at the source code, it seemed to be coded using GWT. However, its Mac look and feel reminds me of Sproutcore. I'm not aware of a look and feel like it for GWT.

I'm really interested on their widget kit, so I started to look for newcomers in this area, without success.

It's hard for me to believe that they custom coded it completely, as it uses many different widgets, charts and effects and it could be, by itself, a huge undertaking.

Do you know if they are using a custom widget kit / framework and, if so, its name?

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Comment: Couldn't hurt to ask them... http://www.woopra.com/contact/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey guys, I'm not using any library beside jQuery. The Woopra web application has been built from scratch from the ground up.

I hope this answers your question.

Elie.
woopra.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer and congratulations: the dashboard, charts using HTML5 canvases, analytics, etc, are *really* great. I thought you were using some kind of widget library (and was googling for it for one full hour without finding it :)

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but again: are you sure you didn't use SproutCore framework? The widgets are exactly the same, the CSS sprites too, the code is using _at least_ the same structure. Sproutcore is a great framework, there is nothing wrong about using it :)

Comment: I'm not using SproutCore. I may have used and modified the "Sprite" image :)

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page source through your browser and find a reference to one of the follow files:

- a long md5sum for the name and ends in .cache.js or .cache.html
- some name that ends with nocache.js or nocache.html

If it has either, you know the site is written using GWT. For example, when looking at the Wave source it references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wave/static/1880D9859FBFB1895A16B35680031427.cache.js">
```

While the web version of Evernote pulls in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/com.evernote.ENWeb/com.evernote.ENWeb.nocache.js?97654'></script>
```

Of course, it's possible to rename these files so just because they're missing, doesn't mean it's not written in GWT. Nevertheless, without these files it's a pretty good bet that they're not using GWT.